# return the match if all words in regex pattern found once

Tags: regex, regex-group

Regex for matching all words in any order and if any word is missing in the string, it will not return any result.

e.g.

```
str = "You’re ready to ask a programming-related question and this form will help guide you through the process.
```

If our requirement is to find the match if str contains both words '**ready**' & '**question**` in any order, then the pattern would be:

`/\bready\b.*\bquestion\b/gi` or `/\bready\b.*\bquestion\b|\bquestion\b.*\bready\b/gi`.

But let's say we need to find a result that contains another word like '**post**' along with '**ready**' & '**question**' then the pattern will not return the match since the word '**post**' is not present in the '**str**'.

[regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

the pattern I was trying

str = 'Then Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King'
pattern = /(\b(the|king|of)\b)/gi

Comment: Works for most engines `(?si)(?:.*?\b(?:(?!\1)(the)|(?!\2)(king)|(?!\3)(of))\b){3}`

https://regex101.com/r/0tsIxo/1
https://regex101.com/r/wVt5BE/1
https://regex101.com/r/8EsstB/1
https://regex101.com/r/qEnAKw/1
JavaScript is still archiac

Comment: A followup note on the archaic remnants of the JavaScript engine. It does not recognize, nor will it consider an assertion or a usage of a back reference to a group that has yet to be defined. Instead of considering the proposition reference as _False_ it decrees the reference forever invalid. This happens in the regex compile stage. Every modern engine, including Dot-Net has fixed this extremely deficient stain on the Regular Expression Language. JavaScript is indeed a dinosaur and remains so.